# Hide objects/User Controls within WrapPanel?

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, user-controls, stackpanel, wrappanel

I've got a `WrapPanel` which will contain several different custom `UserControls`. Depending on the scenario, I may need to filter down which `UserControls` are visible. My goal is that I can switch which controls are visible on the fly by showing/hiding the controls that need to be filtered - thus shifting the controls that are left showing, to the top-left of the panel.

Right now I am simply setting the `Visibility` property of the control to `Visibility.Collapsed` when I don't want them to appear. I thought that because I was using a `WrapPanel`, the rest of the controls would shift to the top-left of the panel.

Instead, after hiding some of the `UserControls`, the controls that **are** still visible stay exactly where they were before, and I am left with gaps between the controls that are still showing. I've opened my app in **Silverlight Spy**, and it shows that the `UserControls` are still actually there (which makes sense) but are simply invisible.

**So my question is:** 
Is there a way that I can show/hide `UserControls` within a `WrapPanel` which allows the *still-visible* `UserControls` to slide to their new positions (all shifting towards the top left - similar to a `StackPanel`)?

I've debated removing the `UserControls` completely from the `WrapPanel` (I think this would work) and storing them in memory until they are needed. Then if I wanted to show/hide other controls, I would get them from my in-memory object. It seems like there should be a better way to do this though.

If anyone has any suggestions or advice, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

-Lloyd

**UPDATE:**

**XAML:** (very simple)

`<toolkit:WrapPanel x:Name="MyLayout" Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" />`

**Code-Behind:** The UserControls are getting added dynamically:

`MyLayout.Children.Add(oUserControl)`

And they are getting set to collapsed dynamically as well:

`oUserControl.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed`

Comment: Setting Visibility as Collapsed should work (and does work for me). For me, setting the Visibility as Hidden demonstrates what you are experiencing above. Could you post some xaml?

Comment: any thoughts on why the ScrollViewer would have that affect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the problem. We added the `WrapPanel` to a `ScrollViewer` recently, and **when I took the ScrollViewer out** I was able to achieve the functionality I wanted.

I'm not sure why the `ScrollViewer` would have that effect though?

Also, I've found that I can leave the `ScrollViewer` **in place** and simply call `.Measure()` on the `WrapPanel` to update the layout.

Neither option makes 100% sense to me, but they do both seem to work.

Comment: Although I doubt MS would pay any attention, file a bug with MS Connect any way.